# How can one get a video thumbnail in Django with InMemoryUploadedFile?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, video-thumbnails

Use case: mobile clients upload videos via mulitiPart/Form and my Django app stores the file on Google Cloud Storage as well as creates a model instance that points to that video.

As Django's request.FILES returns a dictionary of InMemoryUploadedFiles, it makes using mainstream python video processing libraries difficult. All these libraries (ie. CV2, MoviePy etc) expect **file paths** to a video in order to extract frames but I do not have a file paths, Django only provides **InMemoryUploadedFiles**.

Does anyone have any solutions in mind to create a video thumbnail given the time in the video? Please steer clear of solutions that involve saving the InMemoryUploadedFile to a temporary file as the uploaded videos may be quite large. The file already lives in memory, there must be a way to do this.

Comment: hope you can dig something out, see the document: https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.9/recipes1.html#capturing-to-a-stream